# DriverEntry caller

Tags: windows, kernel, device-driver, drivers

I am writing my first device driver.

I am trying to figure out, which process generated a given IRP.

```
Obj->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL] = dirCtl;

NTSTATUS dirCtl(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp);
```

Given the DeviceObject/Irp how can I find out which user-land process tried to query a directory? (e.g. explorer.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time [`PsGetCurrentProcessId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will do the trick since kernel is actually resides in process' memory space.